# Lego Mindstorms NXT - where to find byte codes for bluetooth polling?

Tags: bluetooth, lego-mindstorms

Could not find any any describtion about the bytecodes,
which a mindstorms robot would receive, if it would be polled as a bluetooth slave device.
Do someone know, where to get them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is in the "Bluetooth Development Kit" in the document named "Appendix 2-LEGO MINDSTORMS NXT Direct commands".

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/diablu/downloads/detail?name=NXTCommProcessing-0.91.zip&can=2&q=) is a very useful java library named "diablu", which encapsulates the direct commands.

Comment: You can find the [Bluetooth Development Kit here](http://mindstorms.lego.com/en-us/support/files/default.aspx).